# Finding Minimum Spanning Tree using QGIS

Tags: qgis, road

As shown in the image I have a road network and the intersections as separate layers on QGIS. What I require is to extract the Minimum Spanning Tree connecting all points along the road network.

How may I go about doing this?

[image: The data that I currently have on QGIS]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an already existing tool in processing plugin in `GRASS -> Vector -> v.net.spanningtree`

[image]

You will need to specify the vector line layer and the nodes ( optional )
and in advanced parameters add the type of the geometry of the output layer

and that's it, you'll get a new vector layer with the spanning tree

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may also rely on the '[Minimum Spanning Tree](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/minimum_spanning_tree/)' plugin of QGIS 3.x.

The paper [Geo-MST: A geographical minimum spanning tree plugin for QGIS](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352711020301771) discusses the plugin thoroughly.